# Is it possible to extract the source/medium AND datehour from the Google Analytics API?

Tags: api, google-analytics

I want to extract data from a few years back from the Google Analytics API with the following dimensions and metrics:

- Sessions (ga:sessions)
- Source / Medium (ga:sourceMedium)
- Date and hour (ga:dateHour)

If I fetch data from this year it works fine, but if I try to fetch data from 2 years back, I get no results at all. Anyone knows the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: show some screenshot, pls